# c# pass selected value from dropdownlist to accessdatasource selectparameter

Tags: c#

I have an access data source which loads a listbox values. I am trying to pass a parameter to the accessdatasource but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="customerName" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem value="69" Text="Danny"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="23" Text="Sarah"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="/App_Data/data.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM table WHERE customerID='?'">

<selectparameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="customerID" ControlID="customerName" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
</selectparameters>

<asp:ListBox ID="lstCustomers" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DataTextField="customerName" 
        DataValueField="customerID" Width="175px" Height="365px" 
            onselectedindexchanged="lstCustomers_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>
```

The list comes back as blank... not sure what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: Do you need the single quotes around the parameter placeholder? Try `WHERE customerID = ?` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify.. This was solved by Richard Deeming, but there's no answer to answer. I'll post the code here

It was solved by removing the single quote marks around the ? parameter in the SQL

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="/App_Data/data.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM table WHERE customerID=?">
```